# How to distinguish between added sentences and altered sentences with difflib and nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize, difflib

Downloading [this](https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/reference.nsf/links/02092016062645AM) page and making a very minor edit to it, changing the first *65* in this paragraph to *68*:

[image]

I then run it through the following code to pull out the diffs.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import lxml.html as lh
url = 'https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/reference.nsf/links/02092016062645AM'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()  # get response as list of lines
root = lh.fromstring(content)
section1 = root.xpath("//div[@class = 'column-12']")[0]
section1_text = section1.text_content()

url2 = 'file:///Users/Pyderman/repos/02092016062645AM-modified.html'
response2 = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
content2 = response2.read()  # get response as list of lines
root2 = lh.fromstring(content2)
section2 = root2.xpath("//div[@class = 'column-12']")[0]
section2_text = section2.text_content()

d = difflib.Differ()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(unicode(section1_text))
soup2= bs4.BeautifulSoup(unicode(section2_text))

from nltk import sent_tokenize

sentences = [sentence for string in soup.stripped_strings for sentence in sent_tokenize(string)]
sentences2 = [sentence for string in soup2.stripped_strings for sentence in sent_tokenize(string)]

diff = d.compare(sentences, sentences2)
changes = [change for change in diff if change.startswith('-') or  change.startswith('+')]
for change in changes:
    print(change)
```

Printing the changes gives:

```
- It contains a Title II provision that changes the age at which workers compensation/public disability offset ends for disability beneficiaries from age 65 to full retirement age (FRA).
+ It contains a Title II provision that changes the age at which workers compensation/public disability offset ends for disability beneficiaries from age 68 to full retirement age (FRA).
```

So a change gets marked with a **+**, whether it's a new addition (a brand new full sentence also gets marked with a **+**) or a minor change to an existing sentence. As it stands then, unless my program does some additional processing, it will think that a new sentence was added and another one was removed.

How can we take advantage of the fact that what `difflib` sees as the apparently 'removed' sentence and the apparently 'added' sentence are very similar, in order to determine that we are in fact dealing with an in-place change to an *existing* sentence?

**NOTE:** The solution will need to be able to process potentially several changes in a single page, so it won't be sufficient to apply something like `if sentence1 very similar to sentence 2: then it's a modification`, since there will be several diffs to compare and contrast.

Comment: Note: this may at first glance appear to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35375004/1389110. It's not. I took the suggestion given in the accepted answer there to tokenize the diffs; now I need to distinguish between additions and modifications.

Comment: Use [**`difflib.ndiff`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff)

Comment: @PeterWood I get the same output: http://pastebin.com/xEDASc6U How do you suggest using `ndiff`?

Comment: If you look at the line starting with `?` it indicates where the `+/-` lines are different.

Comment: Can you break the problem down into a simple concise question? I think the background and all is helpful but confusing the question. What is the input? What is the output? And what do you want to solve.

Comment: @alvas The input a list of sentences. The desired output is a separation of the sentences into those that are similar, and those that are unique. Here's how I solved it in the end: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35519081/1389110

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested for-loop element-wise list comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515482/nested-for-loop-element-wise-list-comparison)